# Why do two security lights stay on after a new one was installed?

Tags: wiring

[image]I replaced an old security light and sensor with a new one. When I removed the old sensor it had 5 terminals (`N L E Sl N`). The new sensor only has `L N E`.

There are 2 sets of cables coming out of the wall so in effect I have 6 wires (plus the 3 from the light), so I wired them as follows

- 3 reds into L
- 3 blacks into N  y[image]
- 3 earth's into E

Now the new light works fine and goes off as it should but the other security lights stay on unless I flip the switch in the hall to turn them all off.

Incidentally the new sensor controls them as well.

I have tried looking for an answer and seeng baffled something like a black wire needs to be put in with the live wires that's when I stop!  Doesn't seem "right" so to speak. I can only assume the old sensor which had `Sl` stood for second live and has something to do with that?

Comment: Where on the planet are you located? Wiring standards vary by country. Also, please [edit] your post to include a picture of the wiring diagram included with the new light, and a picture of how the new light is _currently_ wired, and how one of the existing lights is wired.

Comment: What make and model are the lights in question?

Comment: Good Morning Freeman

Comment: @Potherbe -- yes, where on this planet are you for that matter?